# Find any element without the related key

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a product table with some kind of extra key, values used for analytics and stuff. My problem is that if it's easy to find the product with the specified key, it's much more tricky to find the one **without** the key. Let's cut the talk and show the code.

```
SELECT products.*
    FROM products
    JOIN metas ON products.id = metas.product_id
    WHERE
        metas.key = 'mykey' AND
        metas.value = '1'
```

I'll get all the products with the *mykey* key specified and set to the value `1` (the 1 in the example below).

Now I'd like to get all the products without the key *mykey* set (the 2 in the example below). No elements exist in the metas table if the key isn't set.

```
+-------------+     +----------------------------+
| products    |     | metas                      |
+=============+     +============+=======+=======+
|id           |     | product_id | key   | value |
+-------------+     +------------+-------+-------+
| 1           |     | 1          | mykey | 1     |
| 2           |     | 1          | foo   | bar   |
+-------------+     +------------+-------+-------+
```

Extra points if no sub-`select` are hurt in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS` would be an option.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   products as p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT  m.product_id
                   FROM    metas AS m
                   WHERE   m.key = 'mykey'
                           AND m.value = '1'
                           AND m.product_id = p.product_id)
```

Comment: It's not really possible without that extra `SELECT`. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're after, use a `LEFT JOIN` and test for NULL as well:

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
LEFT JOIN metas ON products.id = metas.product_id
WHERE
    (metas.key = 'mykey' AND metas.value = '1')
    OR mets.key IS NULL
```

If you don't want both of these conditions at the same time (not clear from the question), remove the first part of the `WHERE` clause and only test for NULL.

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
LEFT JOIN metas ON products.id = metas.product_id
WHERE
   metas.key IS NULL
```

Comment: The problem is that (as you can see in the question) that row doesn't exist in the metas table, so it doesn't join (even using `left`) because there are nothing to join to. No-subselect wasn't possible here I guess.

Comment: @greut That's what the left join is for. Rows are returned on the left hand table even if there is no match (NULL) on the right table. Did you try it?

Comment: the thing is they are other keys which I don't care about.